# Se me crearon carpetas automáticamente y no sé qué son luego de hacer un deploy

Tags: asp.net, iis

Bunas a todos, les explico, hice una aplicación API utilizando **ASP.NET 4.0, IIS.**

Cuando quiero hacer el Pubish, hago la conexión, poniendo el Server, Site Name, user name, password, destination Url. Todo funciona perfectamente. Cuando hago clic en "Publish" y realizo el deploy de la aplicación, se abre, funciona todo perfecto, y se guarda dentro de un servidor de testing para luego pasarlo a producción .

El tema es el siguiente, en la carpeta del servidor donde estoy apuntando con ip, se me crean varias carpetas que adentro contienen .`dll`, también hay archivos JSON y `.exe`. Hay carpetas como `wwwroot` o `Connected Services` que perteneces a mi aplicación, pero hay otras como `fr`, `es`, `it`, etc, que aparecieron de la nada. Lo único que pienso es que son idiomas, pero se crearon luego de hacer el deploy.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es, si cuando quiera pasarlo a producción, voy a tener algún error si lo desployeo en git, utilizando Jenkins? Que archivos tienen que estar indispensablemente para que funcione? Puedo borrar estas carpetas que se me generaron automáticamente luego de hacer el deploy?

Es la primera vez que hago un deploy de una aplicación, segui paso a paso lo que leí de la documentación de microsoft.

Comment: Pues es que sin saber *qué es tu aplicación o qué hace, o cómo la has hecho* no podemos saber si esas carpetas las has creado tú en el código, si has usado algún sistema de internacionalización que las crea automáticamente o qué... Si tú no sabes de dónde vienen, y eres el único que sabe qué hace el código y cómo lo ha desplegado... imagínate nosotros en la otra punta del mundo y sin tener ni idea de qué carajo estás haciendo :)

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no hay una documentación alguna por el momento para esto, solo pasa en .Net 6, cuando en .Net 5 no pasaba.

Se puede agregar `SatelliteResourceLanguages` ​​para limitar las carpetas.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
</PropertyGroup>
```